# I have already added few country name in my data base but still when I try to list them it is showing nullReference excepetion,How to handle this?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Country";
    }

    <fieldset>
        <legend>List countries</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h5>
                    @Html.ActionLink("New Country", "Create", "Country")
                </h5>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    @foreach (var c in ViewBag.Countries)//NullReference Exceptio
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@c.CountryName</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="/country/edit/@c.CountryID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
                                <a href="/country/Delete/@c.CountryID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

What can be used to handle this ?
```

There are Already 7 To 8 CountryNames in database.But And I have already used nullable variable in program ,How to handle this exception?

// Below is the index method of Country Controller

```
public class CountryController : Controller
    {

        private MyProjectDbEntities db = new MyProjectDbEntities();
        // GET: Country

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = db.Countries.ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Please post the code where you are setting the value of `ViewBag.Countries`?

Comment: and show the trace, please.

Comment: I have added the index method as per your suggestion

Comment: Simple observation (not even debugging) was required!

Answer (score 0):

```
ViewBag.Message = db.Countries.ToList();
```

You are referencing to this as `ViewBag.Countries` in your view.